# String append to JText Area after do other task

Tags: java, swing, sockets, append, jtextarea

```
public void doConnect(){
        try{
            statusArea.append("Starting server.....\n");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
            statusArea.append("Server started.\n");
            statusArea.append("Waiting for client connection....\n");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            statusArea.append("Client connected.\n");
            inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

All strings be appended to text area only after I start server and client connected. So I want to it be shown as my code, step by step. How solve?

Comment: I start server by click a button, when clicked, it look like a toggle button, only after click connect button on client, it'll be normal btn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from updating the screen.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

I suggest you use a `SwingWorker` to execute the socket code in a background thread and use the `SwingWorker`'s functionality to safely update the UI.  See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Something like [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935628/starting-serversocket-on-java-with-user-interfaceswing-freezes/29935769#29935769)