# Can't open Networking app on button click

Tags: java

```
class Server1  {

 private JTextField userText;
 private JTextArea display;
 private ObjectOutputStream output;
 private ObjectInputStream input;
 private ServerSocket server;
 private Socket connection;

 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Server");

 public void changeVisibility() {
     frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 public Server1() {

  JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
  JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
  userText = new JTextField();
  display = new JTextArea();
  display.setBackground(new Color(224, 235, 235));

  JButton send = new JButton("Send");
  try {
   Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("sendmsg.png"));
   Image dimg = img.getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
   send.setIcon(new ImageIcon(dimg));
   send.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

  } catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.println(ex);
  }

  send.setBounds(300, 25, 100, 40);
  send.setBackground(new Color(75, 9, 155));
  send.setForeground(Color.white);
  send.setFocusPainted(false);
  userText.setBounds(10, 25, 300, 40);
  LineBorder panelBorder = new LineBorder(new Color(75, 9, 155), 2);
  TitledBorder TitlePanel1 = new TitledBorder(panelBorder, "CHAT", TitledBorder.LEFT, TitledBorder.TOP, new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20), new Color(75, 9, 155));
  panel1.setBorder(TitlePanel1);
  panel1.setBounds(30, 30, 420, 300);
  display.setBounds(20, 50, 380, 200);
  panel1.add(display);
  display.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(92, 138, 138), 1));
  panel1.setLayout(null);
  LineBorder panelBorder2 = new LineBorder(new Color(75, 9, 155), 2);
  TitledBorder TitlePanel2 = new TitledBorder(panelBorder2, "MESSAGE", TitledBorder.LEFT, TitledBorder.TOP, new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20), new Color(75, 9, 155));
  panel2.add(send);
  panel2.add(userText);
  panel2.setBorder(TitlePanel2);
  panel2.setBounds(30, 350, 420, 80);
  panel2.setLayout(null);

  // Backend starts now
  userText.setEditable(false);
  display.setEditable(false);
  userText.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                    userText.setText("");
                }
            }
        );

  send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    sendMessage(userText.getText());
    userText.setText("");
   }
  });

  frame.add(panel1);
  frame.add(panel2);
  frame.setLayout(null);
  frame.setSize(500, 500);
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  //frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }
 public void startRunning(){
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(9999);
    while(true) {
    try{

        waitForConnection();
        setupStreams();
        whileChatting();
    }catch(EOFException eofException){
        System.out.println("\ " + eofException.getMessage());
        showMessage("\n Server ended the connection!");
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        closeCrap();
    }
}
}
catch(Exception exe) {
exe.printStackTrace();
}
}

public void waitForConnection() throws Exception{
    showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect!");
    connection = server.accept();
    showMessage("\n Now Connected");
   }
   public void setupStreams() throws Exception{
       output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
       output.flush();
       input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
           showMessage("\n The streams are now set up! \n");

   }

   public void whileChatting() throws IOException{
       String message = "You are now connected";
       showMessage(message);
       ableToType(true);
       do{
           try{

               message = (String) input.readObject();

               showMessage("\n" + message);
           }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
               showMessage("Unknown data received!");
           }
       }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END")); 
   }
   public void closeCrap(){
       showMessage("\n Closing Connections... \n");
       ableToType(false);
       try{
           output.close(); 
           input.close(); 
           connection.close(); 
       }catch(IOException ioException){
           ioException.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   private void sendMessage(String message){
       try{
           output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message);
           output.flush();
           showMessage("\nSERVER -" + message);
       }catch(IOException ioException){
           display.append("\n ERROR: CANNOT SEND MESSAGE, PLEASE RETRY");
       }
   }


   private void showMessage(final String text){
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
           new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                   display.append(text);
               }
           }
       );
   }

   private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
           new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                   userText.setEditable(tof);
               }
           }
       );
   }



 /*public static void main(String a[]) {
    Server1 s1 = new Server1();
    s1.changeVisibility();
    s1.startRunning();


 } */

}

class Login {  
     Login()  
        {  
         JFrame f= new JFrame("Login");    

         JButton Login = new JButton("Login");
         Login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Server1 s1 = new Server1();

                s1.changeVisibility();

                s1.startRunning();



             }
         });


         JPanel panel=new JPanel(); 
         panel.setLayout(null);

         panel.setBounds(20,100,340,250); 


         Login.setBounds(50, 160, 100, 30);


         panel.add(Login);


         TitledBorder border = new TitledBorder("LOGIN");
         border.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.LEFT); // Center of panel
         border.setTitlePosition(TitledBorder.TOP);
         border.setTitleFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD, 20));
         border.setTitleColor(new Color(66, 220, 244));
         panel.setBorder(border); 


         f.add(panel);  
         //f.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
                f.setSize(400,420);   
                f.setResizable(false);
                f.setLayout(null);  
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
                f.setVisible(true);
               // Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("ToolTip.png");    

                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        } 

        public static void main(String args[])  
        { 
            new Login(); 


        }  
    }
```

Can't open this Server Frame on button click. It does not show GUI Components and frame also freezes. It works fine when I just run Server frame but I wan't it to open on button click. I'm trying to figure out but in vain. Any suggestions? Same with Client Frame. It does not show me GUI Components.
Please help me with this. I have to make a multi-client chat app .

Comment: Based on your description, I would guess you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread - See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details. You probably want to consider using a `SwingWorker`

Answer (score 0):

So based on this...

```
Login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Server1 s1 = new Server1();
        s1.changeVisibility();
        s1.startRunning();
     }
 });
```

and this...

```
public void startRunning(){
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(9999);
    while(true) {
    try{

        waitForConnection();
        setupStreams();
        whileChatting();
    }catch(EOFException eofException){
        System.out.println("Meny pakra hy issko " + eofException.getMessage());
        showMessage("\n Server ended the connection!");
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        closeCrap();
    }
}
```

It's pretty safe to say that you don't understand how Swing's event dispatching API works.

Essentially, you are setting up a infinite loop within the Event Dispatching Thread, blocking it from processing any new events, including paint requests.

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a viable solution

Comment: I read this but still could not find a way to solve this. I mean I got the mistake but still

Comment: @Rebecca Then you need to start looking [similar examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935628/starting-serversocket-on-java-with-user-interfaceswing-freezes/29935769#29935769) - this is not an uncommon mistake - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155909/java-swing-gui-client-and-server-chat-app-textarea-not-updating/44158305#44158305),